# Angular jasmine test case - unable to access or mock imported var

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

So I have a variable in my auth service ts file which is exported to other services/components after its value is set

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {
  ......
  userDetails = ......
  ......
}
```

`export var userDetails: string;`

It is then imported to multiple services and used

`this.currentUser = JSON.parse(userDetails) as User;`

This works fine but while writing unit test case using jasmine I'm unable to access this userDetials imported variable and its value is always undefined.
I have tried mocking this using `spyOn(authService, 'userDetails').and.returnvalue('name')`
but since it is not a class instance variable it cannot be accessed.
Any solutions for this?

I have tried mocking this using `spyOn(authService, 'userDetails').and.returnvalue('name')`
but since it is not a class instance variable it cannot be accessed.

Comment: I’m not sure what this is an optimal approach but I did additional mock service class which extends original service (in your case it’s AuthService), redefined method which I need (in your case it is userDetails), and then inside particular test reassigned mock service to instant of origin service.